# phppgadmin not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apache2, php

I have looked at the previous answers for this issue.  I updated my apache2 and restarted it (rebooted too, old school).  I made sure I had php on my machine.
I looked at the apache2 error log and it says it detects sigterm, then exits

More explicitly:

```
886:tid 140249392683968] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Oct 12 08:41:10.876939 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 886:tid 140249392683968] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Oct 12 08:41:43.180310 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 893:tid 139728645790656] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Why?

And how can i get past this error?

Comment: As a further note, all I get on the browser when I log into my local IP address (192.168.0.17/phppgadmin) is some html, but no phppgadmin screen or function